# Server is hacked. How to get into wordpress

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I have a site, wordpress is install on it. The site is hacked. I can not login into the wordpress dashboard. I have tried two practices to get login into wp-admin but still I could not get where is the problem.

1. I have changed the password in the wp_users table through
   phpMyAdmin in cpanel.
2. I have also added another database user+password
   and then put the same user name+password on the wp-config.php.

Please me know please if i am wrong or any other solution to get into the wordpress dashboard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: clamp down all non public ports (3306, 8080, 22) to specific IPs. If possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest ensuring that the email address for a full admin user is set to an address that only you have access to (you can change this using phpMyAdmin in wp_users) and then following the "forgotten password" routine via the interface for that user.